# How to fix email signature <img> width that is being stretched horizontally?

Tags: html, email, signature

I'm making an email signature for a client, and on my pc works great, but on anothers the image looks stretched horizontally, it's probably because i set the width to 50% of the image size, I do that because the client will edit this images later, and will need to change the width of that, also for the image looks sharp, i need to use a 2x resolution.(outlook sucks). So that's the code I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>signature</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign=top>
          <p >
            <span>
              <a href="www.client-website.com">
                  <img border=0 src="image-who-will-change-the width.png" alt="Signature" style=" max-width:50%; max-height:117.5px; width:50%;height:117.5px">
              </a>
            </span>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML email signatures _just don't work_. For one thing, most email programs won't load external images automatically (this is to protect user's privacy), so your HTML as-is won't work for most users. The only way this will work is if you embed the image as a MIME multi-part file (*not* as a traditional attachment) which most user-facing email clients don't expose to the user.

Comment: if you have a fluid width, you cannot have a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for your page it will help you to set height or width in percentages.

```
 css:
 html,body{height:100%;
              width:100%;
             }
```

and add height to percentage.